# How to use Javascript to determine what was the last class in a table?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an **if** function that'd check if the second **tr**'s class is **success** or **danger**. Let's say that it'd set the value of **x** to 0 if it's **success** and it'd set the value of **z** to 0 if it's **danger**. I'm not qute sure if it's even possible to do with Javascript but any help is appreciated. Here's some code that I thought can be useful to answering this question, but I can't get my head around it.

```
function hasClass(element, className) {
return element.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className +     "(\\s|$)").test(element.className);
}

var myDiv = document.getElementById('myBetsTable');

hasClass(myDiv, 'success');
```

P.S. These classes are constantly changing.
P.S.2 It must be coded in plain Javascript

[image: HTML]

Comment: Can you use jQuery or do you need plain JS solution?

Comment: I need a plain JS solution (as long as it's possible)

Comment: Can you share with us the code you have tried?

Comment: I've only found some info about .hasClass(), but considering it's jQuery, it's irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @Recuvan have you tried any approaches yet, and if you have, can you show them?

Comment: use `element.classList.contains('someclass')`

Comment: Your title says **last class**, but the question says **second tr**. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap `success` and `danger` classes are used as a method of color coding. This leads me to believe this is some sort of sports betting website.

Because of the sensitivity of this information, it would be much better to enclose this on the server side. This code should definitely not be used in production by itself, but is mainly used to provide a minimal example.

**JavaScript Solution**

You'll want to create a collection of `tr` elements by calling `getElementsByTagName`

In this example, I will be using the `onclick` event attribute to listen for a mouse click. In a production application, this would be used some other way. Once the event has been recorded, the function to check the last bet  (win or loss) will be recorded.

To get the last table row, we can use `rows[rows.length-1]`. We need to use this, because JS arrays are zero indexed.

I've provided a new function for adding new rows to the table. In sports betting, the tables are not fixed, but can change dynamically. Once again, in production this would look much differently.

Upon clicking `Grade Ticket`, a new row will appear. As sports is random and betting is discouraged, you are not guaranteed to win. So, you will either randomly win or randomly lose an event. You can then click `Set Variables` again to see the new result. It will change.

```js
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var betsTable = document.getElementById("bets-table"); 

function setVariables() {
    var lastBet = rows[rows.length - 1];
    alert(lastBet.classList.contains("success") ? "x = 0" : "z = 0");
}

function gradeTicket() {
    var gradedWager = document.createElement("tr");
    var matchup = document.createElement("td");
    var result = document.createElement("td");
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        gradedWager.classList.add("success");
        result.innerHTML = "WIN";
    }
    else {
        gradedWager.classList.add("danger");
        result.innerHTML = "LOSS";
    }
    var teams = document.createTextNode("Team A versus Team B");
    matchup.appendChild(teams);
    gradedWager.appendChild(matchup);
    gradedWager.appendChild(result);
    betsTable.appendChild(gradedWager);
}
```

```css
.success { background: #5cb85c; }
.danger { background: #d9534f; }

#bets-table td {
  padding: 10px;
}

#check-last-bet {
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<table id="bets-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="success">
      <td>Pacers versus Lakers</td>
      <td>WIN $1400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>Celtics versus Clippers</td>
      <td>LOSS $1250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="success">
      <td>Bulls versus Warriors</td>
      <td>WIN $300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>Oregon versus Ohio State</td>
      <td>LOSS $450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="success">
      <td>Manchester United versus Chelsea</td>
      <td>WIN $500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="check-last-bet" onclick="setVariables()">Check Last Bet</button>

</br></br>
<button id="grade-ticket" onclick="gradeTicket()">Grade Ticket</button>
```

Comment: probably want to use `.classList.contains()` so that it matches in another script adds an extra class. also, your script will only see the last row of the last table, it arguable should be "rooted" on a specific table...

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers faster and easier way to do this would be use the native `document.querySelector` method along with the `nth-child` CSS selector.

This avoids scraping through all the TR elements on the page.

```
var tr = document.querySelector("#myBetsTable tr:nth-child(2)");

var cls = tr.getAttribute('class');

if( cls === 'danger' ) {
  console.log(cls);
} else {
  console.log('not danger')
}
```

See [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/3vg92we0/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that checks the class using the `classList` property on DOM objects.

```
function checkClass() {
var td = document.querySelectorAll('tr')[1];

if (td.classList.contains('success')) {
x = 0;
}

else if (td.classList.contains('danger')) {
z = 0;

}
```

If the classes are dynamically changing you can tie the function to an event listener or AJAX call or however the classes change.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the class by counting the rows and get the `classname` of last row

```
  var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
  alert(document.getElementById("myTable").rows[x-1].className);
```

```js
function myFunction() {
     var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
     alert(document.getElementById("myTable").rows[x-1].className);
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="0">
    <td>Row1 cell1</td>
    <td>Row1 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="1">
    <td>Row2 cell1</td>
    <td>Row2 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="2">
    <td>Row3 cell1</td>
    <td>Row3 cell2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Get Class</button>
```